# Passing an expression to a nested grouping in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` object similar to this one

```
library(data.table)

c <- data.table(CO = c(10000,10000,10000,20000,20000,20000,20000),
                SH = c(1427,1333,1333,1000,1000,300,350),
                PRC = c(6.5,6.125,6.2,0.75,0.5,3,3.5),
                DAT = c(0.5,-0.5,0,-0.1,NA_real_,0.2,0.5),
                MM = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B"))
```

and I am trying to perform calculations using nested grouping, passing an expression as an argument. Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```
setkey(c,MM)

mycalc <- quote({nobscc <- length(DAT[complete.cases(DAT)]); 
                 list(MKTCAP = tail(SH,n=1)*tail(PRC,n=1),
                      SQSUM = ifelse(nobscc>=2, sum(DAT^2,na.rm=TRUE), NA_real_),
                      COVCOMP = ifelse(nobscc >= 2, head(DAT,n=1), NA_real_),
                      NOBS = nobscc)}) 


myresults <- c[,.SD[,{setkey=CO; eval(mycalc)},by=CO],by=MM]
```

which produces

```
     MM    CO MKTCAP SQSUM COVCOMP NOBS
[1,]  A 10000 8264.6  0.50     0.5    3
[2,]  A 20000  500.0    NA      NA    1
[3,]  B 20000 1225.0  0.29     0.2    2
```

In the example above I have two elements of the list which use the `ifelse` construct (in the actual code there are 3),  **all doing the same test**  : if the number of observations is greater than 2, then a certain calculation (which is different for each element of the list, and each could be written as a function) is to be performed, otherwise I want the value of the these elements to be NA. Another thing these elements have in common is that they use one and the same column of my `data.table`: the one called `DAT`.

So my question is: is there any way I can do the `ifelse` test only once, and if it is FALSE, pass the value `NA` to the respective elements of the list, and if TRUE, evaluate a different expression for each of the elements of the list?

NOTE: My goal is to reduce the `system.time` (system and elapsed). If this modification will not reduce time and calculations, **bearing in mind I have 72 million observations**, that's an acceptable answer. I also welcome suggestions to change other parts of the code.

EDIT: Results of summaryRprof()

```
$by.total
                          total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"system.time"                  18.94     99.79      0.00     0.00
".Call"                        18.92     99.68      0.10     0.53
"["                            18.92     99.68      0.04     0.21
"[.data.table"                 18.92     99.68      0.02     0.11
"eval"                         18.80     99.05      0.24     1.26
"ifelse"                       18.30     96.42      0.46     2.42
"lm"                           17.70     93.26      0.58     3.06
"sapply"                        8.06     42.47      0.36     1.90
"model.frame"                   7.74     40.78      0.16     0.84
"model.frame.default"           7.58     39.94      0.98     5.16
"lapply"                        6.62     34.88      0.70     3.69
"FUN"                           4.24     22.34      1.10     5.80
"model.matrix"                  4.04     21.29      0.02     0.11
"model.matrix.default"          4.02     21.18      0.26     1.37
"match"                         3.66     19.28      0.86     4.53
".getXlevels"                   3.12     16.44      0.12     0.63
"na.omit"                       2.40     12.64      0.24     1.26
"%in%"                          2.30     12.12      0.34     1.79
"simplify2array"                2.24     11.80      0.12     0.63
"na.omit.data.frame"            2.16     11.38      0.14     0.74
"[.data.frame"                  2.12     11.17      1.18     6.22
"deparse"                       1.80      9.48      0.66     3.48
"unique"                        1.80      9.48      0.54     2.85
"[["                            1.52      8.01      0.12     0.63
"[[.data.frame"                 1.40      7.38      0.54     2.85
".deparseOpts"                  1.34      7.06      0.96     5.06
"paste"                         1.32      6.95      0.16     0.84
"lm.fit"                        1.20      6.32      0.64     3.37
"mode"                          1.14      6.01      0.14     0.74
"unlist"                        1.12      5.90      0.56     2.95
```

Comment: I don't get your result with the double `by`, but I get it exactly with this simpler query : `c[,eval(mycalc),by=list(MM,CO)]`. Is the question fully correct? I don't see what the `setkey=CO` bit is doing, for example.

Comment: And since the question is to reduce time, please post the result of `Rprof()`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I am not sure what Rprof is, but will look it up and post it. About the `by=list(MM,CO)`, I had tried to do the `by` together, but got an error because for some of not all COs exist for each of the MM. But I am sure it is because of something that was missing, such as the list(keys).

Comment: and I was so proud of the nested grouping...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of forming and operating on data subsets like this:

```
setkey(c,MM)
myresults <- c[, .SD[,{setkey=CO; eval(mycalc)},by=CO], by=MM]
```

You could try doing this:

```
setkeyv(c, c("MM", "CO"))
myresults <- c[, eval(mycalc), by=key(c)]
```

This should speed up your code, since it avoids all of the nested subsetting of .SD objects, each of which requires its own call to `[.data.table`.

---

On your original question, I doubt the `ifelse` evaluations are taking much time, but if you want to avoid them, you could take them out of `mycalc` and use `:=` to overwrite the desired values with `NA`:

```
mycalc <- quote(list(MKTCAP = tail(SH,n=1)*tail(PRC,n=1),
                      SQSUM = sum(DAT^2,na.rm=TRUE),
                      COVCOMP = head(DAT,n=1),
                      NOBS = length(DAT[complete.cases(DAT)]))) 
setkeyv(c, c("MM", "CO"))
myresults <- c[, eval(mycalc), by=key(c)]


myresults[NOBS<2, c("SQSUM", "COVCOMP"):=NA_real_]
## Or, alternatively
# myresults[NOBS<2, SQSUM:=NA_real_]
# myresults[NOBS<2, COVCOMP:=NA_real_]
```

Comment: +1 Just seen this after my comments. Do you see what the `setkey=CO` bit is for?

Comment: The first part of the answer didn't make any difference to system.time. Testing it with a subset of my data (one of the 50 years of observations), I got ` 27.416   0.016  27.431 ` using the my version and ` 26.786   0.018  26.803 ` using your version. But I like your way better (I had tried to do something like that but couldn't, and ended up with the nested grouping).

Comment: The second part should increase the time, shouldn't it? Because it will force R to calculate things every time, when in some cases it would skip the calculation and go straight to NA. Also, the test is necessary because when I have less than a certain number of observations I get an error when trying to calculate some of the values (for example, covcomp involves the lagged value of RET. If I only have one observation, the lagged value is non-existent. I could get around it, but it complicates even more)

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- I took it to be detritus from an earlier attempt to get the `by=CO` bit working. While you're here, should the `c("SQSUM","COVCMP"):=NA_REAL_` bit be faster than the pair of calls to two individual `:=` calls? ~Two times faster?  Also is it a general principle of speedy data.table code that one should avoid referencing `.SD` if possible?

Comment: @Vivi -- That's not (unfortunately) how `ifelse` works. As long as even one value of the test is `TRUE`, the **entire** vector of results in the `yes=` argument will be calculated (even though just one value is needed). Likewise for the `no=` argument.  Try this to see that that's how it works: `x <- c(1, -1); ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), sqrt(x), 2*x)`. (Also, note that I just slightly edited the post, to remove the now-unnecessary pre-calculation of `nobscc`.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien what you say makes sense. I got a few errors trying to change the code that can be explained by R evaluating both expressions in all cases.

Comment: @Josh On the two questions: i) Yes, that fits with `NOBS<2` vector scan and scanning result to find `TRUE` taking all the time. Once you know the (few in this case) row numbers, the update by reference is very quick ii) Yes, `.SD[...]` is definitely to be avoided if there's a choice. Using `.SD` on it's own is ok (e.g. with `.SDcols`) and `lapply(.SD,...)` is now just as fast as `j=list(...)`. If you turn on `verbose` it shows you what `options(datatable.optimize=Inf)` does to `j` when `j` contains `lapply` or `mean` (so far).

Comment: @Vivi Just call `Rprof()`, then run your test as normal (27 secs), then run `Rprof(NULL)` and finally `summaryRprof()` and that's it. That's the output we need.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I got it. It is in the edit to my question. I don't know how to read this, but I think that the `lm` function is taking a lot of the time, correct? I am changing this part of my code since I only need one coefficient of the OLS regression, and `lm` calculates a whole bunch of stuff....

Comment: @Vivi Ok I see the output but where (on earth) in the question's code is a call to `lm`?  Now that the nested part of the question is answered, and you now know how to profile, maybe accept Josh's answer and ask a new question if you get stuck performance tuning.

Comment: @MatthewDowle fair enough. I ran the Rprof() using the full code, which has `lm` (but you are right, I shouldn't have). It seems like the nested bit and the ifelse aren't the problem anyway.

Comment: @Vivi One last note. Given that the calls to `lm()` are taking 93% of the time, it appears that the first part of what I gave you actually speeds the `data.table`-related parts up by 35% or more.